# What are bounce domains good for?

Tags: email

I'm running my own spam filter. Sometimes I see newsletters being sent from a bounce domain (eg. `bounce-1355_html-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx@bounce.news.xxx.ch`. Does anyone know what such domains are good for?

Thanks.

Comment: Likely because `news.xxx.ch` itself isn't set up to handle bounce notifications for the email sender, which is often a third-party like SES or Sendgrid or whatnot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only thing the return path is good* for it receiving  nondelivery and delivery reports

So, typically it's for end-to-end delivery tracking. it gives the operator of bounce.news.xxx.ch information about if the email bounces.